# Plots gets squished causing text to be unreadable when plotting multiple plots besides each other using grid.arrange

Tags: r, ggplot2

for a school assignment, I have made three plots in total, that I want to arrange in a 2x2 array with 1 plot at the top and the two others at the bottom.
example of one of the three plots:

```
p1 <- ggplot(test.total, aes(x=object, y=preference.ratios)) + geom_boxplot(aes(colour=object), lwd=0.95, outlier.colour = "white") + geom_hline(yintercept=1, color="red", lwd=0.95) + geom_jitter(aes(color=object), width = 0.1, size=3) + theme_light() + scale_colour_manual(values=c("#33a02c", "#6a3d9a")) + labs(title="preference ratio novel object over familiar object", x=" ", y="preference ratio novel(sec)/familiar(sec)")  + geom_signif(comparisons = list(c("Cup", "Legoes")), map_signif_level = TRUE, annotations = "Welch two sample t-test, p=0.004482*", textsize = 4, vjust = -0.5) + stat_summary(fun.data = function(x) data.frame(y=median(x), label = paste("Median = ", round(median(x), 2))), geom="text", size=4, vjust=c(8.6,19.8)) + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.4,0.4,0.1,0.4), "lines"))
```

this gives me the following plot:
[image: p1]

as you can see, the vjust adjustments put the medians on the same height, and the annotations are in the top of the plot.

When I want to combine this plot with two other similar plots in one grid, I tried the following code:

```
#make grobs of each plot
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
g2 <- ggplotGrob(p2)
g3 <- ggplotGrob(p3)
grob_list <- gList(g1, g2, g3)
# arrange plots in p1 at the top and p2 and p3 at the bottom using grid.arrange
grid.arrange(grobs=grob_list, layout_matrix=rbind(c(1,NA), c(3,4)), widths=c(0.5,0.5), heights=c(0.5,0.5))
```

this results in the following:
[image: image all three plots together]

as you can see, the plots are in the right place and have equal sizes, but the text from geom_signif and geom_stat_summary are not clearly or not at all visible anymore.

I've tried playing around with the widths and heights, but that does not seem to help for that text. Anyone know what to do?

Thank you very much in advance!